# why referencing non-existent property of an object in javascript doesn't return a reference error?

Tags: javascript

If I try to reference a non-existent variable, I get ReferenceError in JavaScript. Why referencing a non-existent object property returns 'undefined'?
Here is some code, provided I'm writing it in a browser:

```
alert(a);
ReferenceError: a is not defined //error is thrown
alert({}.a)
undefined //no error
```

Comment: Can you post some code?  If I was a gambling man I'd say it does exist but is either null or empty.  Have you debugged with the console?

Comment: Are you asking why the language is designed that way? @MikeHometchko - I'd take your bet: non-existent properties do return `undefined`, whereas properties that are `null` return `null` (and if by "empty" you mean an empty string that would return, well, an empty string); to make things even more confusing, properties that do exist but that have been assigned the value `undefined` also return `undefined`.

Comment: @nnnnnn I think he is...

Comment: @nnnnnn you have 1 more minute to expand your comment even more... go, go, go! :D

Comment: @nnnnnn Oh wow that is weird, I've never noticed this.  +1 to OP for waking me up from the Matrix, my life has been a lie!

Answer (score 24):

That's just how the language works. Its object-based approach is very flexible, and you can dynamically add, update, and remove properties from objects at runtime. Accessing one that is currently not existing should yield `undefined` instead of raising an exception. This, for example, allows checking for existence and type in a single expression:

```
if (prop in obj && typeof obj[prop] == "function") obj[prop]();
// can be written shorter:
if (typeof obj[prop] == "function") obj[prop]();
```

You can get the value without using it. Using `undefined` then will throw in most circumstances.

In contrast, variables are declared statically in their scope. Accessing an undeclared variable is *always* an error, which legitimates throwing `ReferenceError`s.

Comment: Thanks, but I know all that. I'm interested in "behind the scenes" processes, like for example [why you can delete properies of custom objects with `delete` operator, and can't delete variables and functions.](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/)

Comment: For that, I'd recommend reading [the ECMAScript specification](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/), specifically the sections 8.6, 8.7, and 8.12 on objects, 11.2.1 and 11.4.1 for the operators, and maybe 10[.2] about variables and scopes. However, the spec doesn't explain *why*, it just says *what*.

Comment: Note that "ReferenceError" exists only in strict mode. A summary of changes in strict mode is in [Annex C](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-C). Strict mode restricts unresolvable references. Object properties are not unresolvable references.

Comment: MDN mentions that non-existing properties *can* also throw an error (it's a warning, actually), depending on non-default browser settings. I wouldn't try to cover it though since it's an edge case imo. — "(Firefox only) ReferenceError warning which is reported only if javascript.options.strict preference is set to true." — https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Undefined_prop + http://kb.mozillazine.org/Javascript.options.strict