# reusable web page elements with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a bunch of little bits of HTML that I'd like to reuse on various pages and have looked at several ways to do this.  I've come up with the following solution that uses a javascript function object to create the element and insert it into the page.  Here is an example:

```
    <div id="id"></div>
    <script>var v = function(divid){
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    el.innerHTML="<input type=\"button\" onclick=\"alert(\"hello world\"/>";}</script>
```

This is just a simple contrived example.  The script creates a button and puts it into the div and assigns a function to it.  In a real example the javascript would be a separate file and the function might create several HTML elements that interact with one another.

I then took this further and added object parameters.  Here is the HTML:

```
    <div id="btndiv">{"button":"Click","message":"clicked"}</div>
    <script>var v = new PopButton(id);</script>
```

This is easy to read in an HTML page where I add the block element then the object is created in place.  The widget object code looks like this:

```
    function PopButton(btndiv) {
     this.div = document.getElementById(btndiv);
     var jasontext = this.div.innerText;
     var jason = null;
     try {
      jason = JSON.parse(jasontext);
     } catch(e) {
      jason = {"button":"Click","message":"clicked"};
     }
     var h = "<button type=\"button\" id=\""+btndiv+"btn\"";
     h += " onclick=\"PopButtonClicked("+btndiv+"msg)\">"+jason.button+"</button>";
     h += "<div id=\""+btndiv+"msg\" style=\"display:none\">"+jason.message+"</div>";
     this.div.innerHTML = h;
    }
    function PopButtonClicked(msgel) {
      if(msgel.style.display === "none") {
        msgel.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        msgel.style.display = "none";
     }
    }
```

In other words, I use the innerText to send parameters to the javascript object and then replace that with the HTML that makes up the widget.

This is just a simple example to show parameter passing.  More complex widgets can be built with this technique but I'm unsatisfied with parameter passing.  In my implementation if the JSON.parse() encounters an error then the whole parameter is dropped and a default is set.

Is there a way to pass parameters that would allow for optional parameters?  For example if I parsed the innerText with just '{"button":"clickme"}' and didn't include the "message" part that wouldn't generate an error if I referenced 'jason.message'?

Thank you, in advance.

Comment: Why not use `PHP include` or iframe to load templates (reusable code parts)? Also it would be easier to just toggle a class with `dispaly: block/none` instead of using long if/else statements

Comment: How about [Web Components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components) ~ create once and re-use simply by including your own tag

Comment: PHP doesn't solve this problem well for two reasons: First, I'd like to have multiple instances of the widgets on the page and using javascript associates the widgets with a particular ID; second, it's easier to see the widget in place in the HTML.

Comment: With web components widget parameters look easy to implement but I can't see how to attach specific code to an HTML element.  Reference [Medium](https://medium.com/tunaiku-tech/create-your-first-web-component-with-vanilla-javascript-af93cbf3a70f)

Comment: Not entirely sure about your meaning but passing parameters to a component is generally done using attributes. Incidentally having looked at the code in the first portion of Javascript I think there may be a mistook - `function(divid)` and then `document.getElementById(id);` ~ `id` is not defined...

Comment: In the `PopButton` function what is the point of `var thisBtn = this;` ~ surely at that point `this` is the `window` object and serves no useful purpose to your function?

Comment: corrected typo making it same divid; dropped the thisbutton parameter - I'd used that construct in another of these widgets.

Comment: "passing parameters to a component" is basically the key to my question. I'd like sort of a custom control in HTML/Javascript.  In HTML I include a block level element and then call a javascript constructor to put HTML into that element where the HTML could include javascript that acts on the "control".  The parameters are used for the appearance of the "control" and/or the function of it.

Comment: You can [reference a non-existent object property without encountering an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19317943/why-referencing-non-existent-property-of-an-object-in-javascript-doesnt-return). But even if it did encounter an error, you could still wrap it in a try/catch block, so does it even matter?

Comment: I see, so I could use a default parameter by wrapping the reference in a try/catch and in the catch clause assign a default value to the object.  That sounds like it solves my problem - I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

kmoser came up with the solution.  Here's the pseudocode:

```
    try { jason = JSON.parse(inputtext);
    } catch(e) { jason = set defaults ...;}
    param = (jason.parameter === undefined) ? "default" : jasaon.parameter;
```

I first attempted putting it in a try/catch when making the assignment but executing the assignment `param = jason.parameter` didn't trigger an exception so I simply tested for whether the object member was undefined.